# Error 409 Conflict with Azure Table Storage and unique entries

Tags: azure-table-storage

What would be causing the 409 conflict error with Table storage if I know for sure that the entries that I was trying to add to the table have a unique partition key + row key combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table Servıce Error codes are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Table-Service-Error-Codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN

In addition to entity already exists scenario, you can also get 409 if you want to create an existing table or if the table is marked to be deleted and you try to create it ie. delete and create same table without any delay in between.

But most likely cause is that the entity you try to insert is already inserted. If you are trying to insert same entity concurrently etc. So may be provide more detail on your system, and the checks you make to conclude that the entity you insert is not inserted already.